# MySQL SELECT query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I have a query which has a list of values for checking against a single column in a multi column table.

Example query ONE......

```
SELECT `name`, `sleeps` 
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `town`='bude' OR `town`='newquay' OR `town`='widemouth' OR `town`='polzeath' OR `town`='crantock' OR `town`='perranporth' OR `town`='Porthmeor' OR `town`='St Ives' OR `town`='porthtowan'
```

Example query TWO......

```
SELECT `name`, `sleeps` 
FROM `properties` 
WHERE `town` IN ('bude', 'newquay', 'widemouth', 'polzeath', 'crantock', 'wadebridge', 'Porthmeor', 'St Ives', 'porthtowan')
```

-   -

I have run both in phpmyadmin and found the query speed to be very similar, all be it with a table of approx 5,000 records.

In terms of performance and durability when the table contains more data is is best to go for the 'IN' style query or use multiple instances OR?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple test result,

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 ... id = 10000
This query took 0.1139 seconds

SELECT * FROM item WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...10000)
This query took 0.0413 seconds
```

**IN** faster than **OR**

Comment: Great! +1 for giving evidence because science is all about expriments and evidence.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the less efficient one into the other. So I think the answer should rather depend on the readability of each (where I think that `IN` is more efficient)

**IN** is 3 times faster than **OR**

Answer (score 2):

I tried some querys, IN is faster everytime.